# How can I train a neural net with multiple categorical inputs?

Tags: neural-networks

I think I understand how to create a neural net that has multiple categorical inputs, but I don't seem to be able to invoke `NetTrain` successfully on it.

As a concrete example, suppose the data I want to train against maps two categorical inputs, each drawn from classes `{a, b, c}`, to a numerical tensor with dimensions `{2}`.

Some data looks like this:

```
In[1]:= data = 
 Table[<|"Input1" -> RandomChoice[{a, b, c}], 
    "Input2" -> RandomChoice[{a, b, c}]|> -> RandomReal[1, 2], 10]

Out[1]= {<|"Input1" -> b, "Input2" -> a|> -> {0.833467, 0.928599}, 
         <|"Input1" -> a, "Input2" -> c|> -> {0.984507, 0.38375},
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> a|> -> {0.0477534, 0.750165},
         <|"Input1" -> a, "Input2" -> a|> -> {0.641454, 0.55485},
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> a|> -> {0.854673, 0.0175461}, 
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> b|> -> {0.518462, 0.00939247}, 
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> c|> -> {0.323348, 0.993629}, 
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> c|> -> {0.757127, 0.185508}, 
         <|"Input1" -> b, "Input2" -> b|> -> {0.634778, 0.127342}, 
         <|"Input1" -> c, "Input2" -> a|> -> {0.173669, 0.0696255}}
```

I expected the following neutral net to be compatible with this data:

```
In[2]:= net = 
 NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], 2},
   {{NetPort["Input1"], NetPort["Input2"]} -> 1, 
    1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output1"]}, 
  "Input1" -> {"Class", {a, b, c}, "UnitVector"}, 
  "Input2" -> {"Class", {a, b, c}, "UnitVector"}]

Out[2]=
```

[image: Neutral net with multiple categorical inputs]

And at first it seems to work:

```
In[3]:= NetInitialize[net][<|"Input1" -> a, "Input2" -> c|>]

Out[3]= {-0.186007, -0.193141}
```

But `NetTrain` fails:

```
In[4]:= NetTrain[net, data]

Out[4]= ("Input spec cannot be used with the given net.")
```

Any ideas what is happening here? Am I use `CatenateLayer` correctly?

Answer (score 11):

1. format of data is incorrect, you should make separate key for output
2. you forgot about `NetEncoder` for inputs

```
data = Table[
   <|
    "Input1" -> RandomChoice[{a, b, c}],
    "Input2" -> RandomChoice[{a, b, c}],
    "Output" -> RandomReal[1, 2]
    |>
   ,
   10
   ];

net = NetGraph[
  {
   CatenateLayer[],
   2
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input1"] -> 1,
   NetPort["Input2"] -> 1,
   1 -> 2
   },
  "Input1" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {a, b, c}, "UnitVector"}],
  "Input2" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {a, b, c}, "UnitVector"}],
  "Output" -> 2
  ]

net = NetTrain[net, data]
```

Comment: Cool, this does work. Any insight into why the NetEncoder for inputs is required? I got the impression from the docs that it is implicit with "Input1" -> {"Class", etc}.